# Autoplay TuneIN embed code

Tags: embed, tunein

I want to embed TuneIN player to my site so it autoplay.
Code is:

```
<iframe src="https://tunein.com/embed/player/s281461/" style="width:100%;height:100px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

I tried including ?autoplay=1 in url but no luck.
Note: I won't use custom player because it won't provide currently listening track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your TuneIN embed stream to autoplay here is code:

```
<iframe src="http://tunein.com/embed/player/s96692?autoplay=true"
style="width:100%;height:100px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

Just replace

> http://tunein.com/embed/player/s96692

with your station url.

Comment: Any idea on how to remove share button appearing on embedded streams?

Comment: Thanks, the autoplay=true its functional for me